# The string shows the same content but the program says they are different strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hye guys,
I followed the link to mount NAS to my PC.

```
https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS#t2
```

I copied the command line by line and checked my spelling and folder name are correct. But somehow it still couldn't find the folder path. However, if I type the folder myself everything works. So I tested 2 strings, one is copied and one is from me in visual code. Their content looks the same, but the program just showed they are different strings. Anyone knows why? many appreciated.

```
str_Copy = "sudo mount -t nfs 169.x.x.x:/volume1/path /mnt/sharedfolder"
str_Writ = "sudo mount -t nfs 169.x.x.x:/volume1/path /mnt/sharedfolder"
print(str1==str2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to avoid encode issues.

```
import unicodedata
str_copy = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', str_copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings are actually differnt, because of non basic spaces being used in one of them.

Copy and paste the code in a hex editor, and you'll see the difference.

I pasted your code in a Vim buffer, saved it and then hex dumped it, this happened:

```
$ hexdump -C mierda 
00000000  22 73 75 64 6f 20 6d 6f  75 6e 74 e2 80 83 2d 74  |"sudo mount...-t|
00000010  e2 80 83 6e 66 73 e2 80  83 31 36 39 2e 78 2e 78  |...nfs...169.x.x|
00000020  2e 78 3a 2f 76 6f 6c 75  6d 65 31 2f 70 61 74 68  |.x:/volume1/path|
00000030  20 2f 6d 6e 74 2f 73 68  61 72 65 64 66 6f 6c 64  | /mnt/sharedfold|
00000040  65 72 22 0a 22 73 75 64  6f 20 6d 6f 75 6e 74 20  |er"."sudo mount |
00000050  2d 74 20 6e 66 73 20 31  36 39 2e 78 2e 78 2e 78  |-t nfs 169.x.x.x|
00000060  3a 2f 76 6f 6c 75 6d 65  31 2f 70 61 74 68 20 2f  |:/volume1/path /|
00000070  6d 6e 74 2f 73 68 61 72  65 64 66 6f 6c 64 65 72  |mnt/sharedfolder|
00000080  22 0a                                             |".|
00000082
$ _
```

If you look carefully, lengths are different, because contents are very different, even at first sight they looked like the same.

If you just write spaces on top of the non standard spaces warned by the hex dump, you'll end up with two equal strings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "If you just write spaces on top of the non standard spaces warned by the hex dump, you'll end up with two equal strings."